# Windows update possibly causing driver issue with USB ports

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, keyboard, mouse

With the Windows Update I had problems on all systems with USB ports. 
Toshiba laptop, Dell laptop, and Dell desktop. I was able to work around problems by deleting the update causing the problem on the two laptops and power management of the USB ports but the desktop is a bigger issue. Without USB ports working my mouse and keyboard will not work so device will allow me to log in. I am helpless.

I rebooted in safe mode and mouse & keyboard worked but booting with Windows, I can't do anything. Only thing I haven't tried but think I will is a PS/2 mouse keyboard inserting a port into my system. Do you think this will work with Windows 10? Only combo PS/2 ports I can find are 32-bit. Any other ideas? I am not a techy so please be simple.

Comment: PS2 drivers are built into Windows. It’s not clear what your question is exactly

Comment: What do you mean "Only combo PS/2 ports I can find are 32-bit"? All internal interfaces are no less than 32-bit. Do you mean that your PC doesn't have the regular PCI slot, and has only PCIe slots?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like mean that your PC doesn't have an old 32-bit PCI slot, and has only modern PCIe. Yet typical PS/2 port adapters are only made in PCI-32 format.

Then your solution is to get a PCIe-to-PCI adapter, like [the StarTech card](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815158165)

[image]

And then plug in the more common PCI to PS/2 adapter card,

[image]

This should work with default Win10 PS/2 drivers. This should be a temporary solution until you fix your USB drivers.

There are less expensive alternatives to PCIe-to-PCI adapter on Aliexpress.